# How to efficiently query MSSQL and Mongo dB?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, mongodb, mongoose, sequelize.js

I'm using both MSSQl(`Sequelize`) and  Mongo dB(`mongoose`) in a project for storing data. I have a scenario like this

1. Retrieve `_id` from MSSQL table
2. Retrieve data from collection using the above collected `_id`

Currently my code will look like this (not real code, just approach):

```
getIdFromTable().then(data)=> {
   let ids = data.map(i => i["_id"])
   getDataFromColUsingIds(ids).then(data=> {
     // Do my stuff
   })
})
```

But I know this is not the best approach, if I fetch 10k + records then this approach will be slow.
Can someone educate me how can I do it efficiently ?

Comment: Fetching data from one database and then using it to fetch data from another database is generally not very efficient, however you could use streaming or Promise.all()

Comment: @Haukland I can't use `Promise.all` cause I need the `_id` to do that. How can I stream data ? do yo know any article about that ?

Comment: NodeJS has official documentation of their stream api at nodejs.org

Comment: In short you can get a stream using `getIdFromTable().stream();` and then hooking onto the "data" event and the "end" event

Comment: I think your approach should be best, since you'd rather fetch a lot of IDs in bulk than do it one on one. At least that is the case with *some* databases. Although, perhaps you wanna split it in lesser batches as to not overwhelm the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stream rather than waiting for the whole dataset to be loaded:

```
const stream = getIdFromTable().stream();

stream.on('data', function(item) {
  getDataFromColUsingId(item._id).then(data => {
    // Do your stuff
  });
});

stream.on('end', function() {
  // All data has been processed
});
```

As I mentioned in a comment, it would be better to avoid fetching data from one database and then using it to fetch data from another if possible